# Shapefile, clip or project first when both are necessary

Tags: arcmap, clip, data-management, workflow

This is a question mostly out of curiosity, but I do it enough if there were a better choice I would stick with that.

Using ArcMap 10.6, when a shapefile needs both clipped and projected is there an order in which one workflow is faster? Or would I just need to experiment to find out?

Answer (score 3):

Mmm, really it depends on what you need the final outcome to be. Assuming you would want the outcome to be compatible in later analyses with the file you are clipping it to, I would re-project it first, then clip it to the file! If you would do it the other way around, the end result would probably not be perfectly clipped. That being said, observe caution if you are going to use more data that is in the former coordinate system to perform an analysis on the clipped shapefile, as these will now have different coordinate systems.

Comment: It depends on what coordinate system the clip is in, to get neat edges clip in the coordinate system of the clip. If the shapefile to be clipped is particularly large clipping first to a buffer of the clip then projecting the rough clip before the final clip gives a slight performance increase - no point projecting lots of features that are just going to be discarded.